# SQL sum based on category

Tags: mysql, sql

'[image: SQL DATA]'

I am trying to get sum of the columns A,B,C,D for all different categories. Tried with case statement but doesn't looks like a optimised code in SQL.

`SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = '1' THEN a ELSE 0 end), 
SUM(CASE WHEN Category = '1' THEN b ELSE 0 end)
from table`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Hint: `sum()`, `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Category, SUM(a) suma, SUM(b) sumb, SUM(c) sumc, SUM(d) sumd
FROM table
GROUP BY Category
```

This will get one row for each distinct value in `Category`, and the sum, for each column, for each row that has that value of `Category`.

So for your case, it will look something like:

```
Category suma sumb sumc sumd
1        12   7    25   3471
2        15   10   37   374
... etc.
```